# What is the equivalent of Java's HashMap in AutoHotkey?

Tags: hashmap, autohotkey

I have a set of abbreviated department names. I need to create a script which can map these abbreviations with their official titles. (For example: ADMIN → Administration)

In Java I could accomplish this using a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

```java
public static void main() {
   HashMap hm = new HashMap(); // create hash map

   hm.put("ADMIN", "Administration");  // add elements to hashmap
   hm.put("RAD",   "Radiologist");
   hm.put("TECH",  "Technician");

   System.out.println("ADMIN is an abbreviation for " + hm.get("ADMIN"));
}
```

Is there an equivalent solution for this in AutoHotkey?

Comment: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/86523-list-and-dictionary-structures-in-autohotkey/  and others, just a google search away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can implement key-value pairs using an [Associative Array](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Associative_Arrays)

> An associative array is an object which contains a collection of
>   unique keys and a collection of values, where each key is associated
>   with one value. Keys can be strings, integers or objects, while values
>   can be of any type. An associative array can be created as follows:
>
> ```
> Array := {KeyA: ValueA, KeyB: ValueB, ..., KeyZ: ValueZ}
> ```

Here is an array which uses a job's shortened name (`key`) to find the full display name (`value`).

```
JobArray := {ADMIN:"Administration", TECH:"Technician", RAD:"Radiologist"}

; Check if key is present
if (JobArray.HasKey("ADMIN"))
    MsgBox, % "ADMIN is an abbreviation for " . JobArray["ADMIN"]
else
    MsgBox, % "No display name found"
```